# “You do not appear to be using the nvidia x server" in BumbleBee

Tags: drivers, nvidia, bumblebee

When I open Nvidia X Server, it says "You do not appear to be using the nvidia x server" and tell me to run nvidia-xsettings. After looking for some answers, some said that xorg.conf is not compatible with Optimus laptops.
From this answer, it says should be able to run nvidia settings with it and it works.

> optirun nvidia-settings -c :8

However, it does not seem to be persistent and only work when I open like that. Is it possible to put this option in startup.
The reason I am looking for the solution is because I am not able to run steam games anymore after installing BumbleBee driver.

I am using Nvidia 940M.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already solved this or switched to another setup by now but...

To run bumblebee drivers on steam games, you can either open steam with optirun (or primusrun), which will run steam *and* all the games on it on the GPU, which uses more power just having steam open, or you can open steam normally and choose which games to run on the GPU by right-clicking the game->Properties->Set Launch Options->optirun(or primusrun) %command%

If the steam/the games configured for the GPU don't open after you try that, switch commands (optirun->primusrun or primusrun->optirun). If it still doesn't work there's a problem with your bumblebee driver installation.

To make nvidia-settings open with the desktop/menu shortcut:

1. Open a terminal
2. `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/nvidia-settings.desktop`
3. Find the line starting with Exec=
4. Make the line 'Exec=optirun nvidia-settings -c :8' (without the quotes, of course)
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save
6. <kbd>Ctrk</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close